# Calling function inside a loop but the loop stops - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)    
{                
    function(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());   
}
```

I tried to loop the selected values from the gridview and put it inside a 
datatable. Now, my problem is that when I tried the code above to pass the 
value from datatable to my function. It works, but just once and the loop 
stops. Can somebody help me please?

The function is for downloading pdf file.

Comment: How many rows dt has. If it runs only one time may be there is only one row in data table.

Comment: There must be some additional code here.  How is `dt` set?

Comment: I think the dt is working, when i put break point. It gets the selected values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is sending a binary pdf file to the response stream, it may be calling `Response.End` which would halt the thread.

If you want to send multiple files the client needs to make multiple requests or the server needs to package them up, like in a zip file.

Comment: You're right sir, when i remove the Response.End, the error said multiple disposition. now, my problem is I don't know how to put all the pdf into zip then download it.

Answer (score 0):

Try
function function_Name(code) {}